# FF and IE - way of handeling \n in textarea

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, input, textarea, line-breaks

Im doing a textarea with jeditable. The content is saved and loaded from a database. But im having some problems in the way IE and FF handles linebreaks differently.

After some debugging i've found a mysterious behavior in FF. For example if i input in textarea:

```
1
2
```

It will return

```
1<br>2
```

Which is fine. But if i write:

```
1
2
3
```

It returns

```
1<br>2<br>
3
```

How come? And how am i supposed to do regexp on this abnormal behaviour.

Atm. im doing this regexp:

```
  data      : function(value, settings) {
      /* Convert <br> to newline. */
      retval = value(/<br[\s\/]?>/gi, '\n');
      return retval;
 },
```

Which works fine in IE, but in FF (because of this behaviour) it returns more linebreaks than supposed to.

Can you help ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing how jeditable works and how you're using it. You should have posted a testcase or, better yet, try to reproduce the problem with minimum amount of code (i.e. without any plugins) first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're expecting the text to have no newlines in it, why not just strip them out before you convert the `<br>`s to newlines?

```
value = value.replace(/(\r\n|[\r\n])/g,'');
retval = value.replace(/<br[\s\/]?>/gi, '\n');
```

Comment: It still puts an extra \n in firefox-.-

Comment: I guess the regexp doesnt work. When using var retval = value.replace(/\\n/gi,'TEST'); it doesnt outputs any "TEST"

Comment: @s0mmer so try a different regex, I took a new one from here: http://lawrence.ecorp.net/inet/samples/regexp-format.php

Comment: I ended up using the idea presented by robertc but with a working regexp. Thanks